# How to call a function on start in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I created new page in my app but i want to call function without set state

this is my function:

```
yaziGetir(Mahalle mahalle) {
    FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("Mahalleler")
        .doc(mahalle.neighborhood)
        .get()
        .then((gelenVeri) {
      setState(() {
        gelenYaziBasligi = gelenVeri.data()['Eğitim'];
        gelenYaziIcerigi = gelenVeri.data()['Geri Dönüşüm'];
      });
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

InitState(){}  ,where you can call your function

Answer (score 5):

You should make the call of your function in initState rather then in widget tree as everytime the widget is rebuild, it will call the function to execute again and again(leading to more reads).

```
@override
void initState()
{
super.initState();
yourFunction();//call it over here
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can call the function before the build method. For example :

```
  void yourFunction() {
    // This is your function
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // Call the function before build method
    yourFunction();
    return Scaffold(
      body: Text('ok'),
    );
  }
```

In your case because you're using a **async** function you should use a **FutureBuilder**

```
  Future<void> yourAsyncFunction() async {
    // This is your function
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
      // Waiting your async function to finish
      future: yourAsyncFunction,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        // Async function finished
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
          // To access the function data when is done
          // you can take it from **snapshot.data**
          return Scaffold(
            body: Text('ok'),
          );
        } else {
          // Show loading during the async function finish to process
          return Scaffold(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
        }
      },
    );
  }
```